# How to load lists in pelilcanconf.py from external file

Tags: pelican

There are different lists available in pelicanconf.py such as

```
SOCIAL = (('Facebook','www.facebook.com'),)
LINKS =
```

etc.

I want to manage these content and create my own lists by loading these values from an external file which can be edited independently. I tried importing data as a text file using python but it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly did not work? Can you provide code?

You can execute arbitrary python code in your `pelicanconf.py`.

Example for a very simple CSV reader:

```
# in pelicanconf.py
def fn_to_list(fn):
    with open(fn, 'r') as res:
        return tuple(map(lambda line: tuple(line[:-1].split(';')), res.readlines()))

print(fn_to_list("data"))
```

CSV file `data`:

```
A;1
B;2
C;3
D;4
E;5
F;6
```

Together, this yields the following when running `pelican`:

```
# ...
((u'A', u'1'), (u'B', u'2'), (u'C', u'3'), (u'D', u'4'), (u'E', u'5'), (u'F', u'6'))
# ...
```

Instead of printing you can also assign this list to a variable, say `LINKS`.